# Como passar por uma lista vazia no python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loop, numpy

Estou querendo criar um loop por uma lista que contém DataFrames, mas pode ocorrer que em um determinado índice dessa lista, o DataFrame esteja vazio o que faz com que o loop pare de ocorrer. Como eu posso contornar isso. Abaixo está o meu caso.

Esse é o meu código

```
for i in range(0,len(df_pt)):
    for j in range(0,len(df_pt[i])):
        df_pt[i][j][0]
```

onde os índices 0 e 5, são...

```
>>> df_pt[0]
array([[       nan],
       [       nan],
       [0.0567627 ],
       [0.29394531]])
```

```
>>> df_pt[5]
array([], shape=(2, 0), dtype=float64)
```

eu quero passar por todos os elementos, que são cerca de 3675 índices

Comment: se você colocar um `if np.isnan(df_pt[i][j]):  continue`  ou outra condicional para verificar se existe valor na matriz  na linha i coluna j provavelmente já resolveria

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Porque vc quer passar por todos os indices? Dependendo do que você tem por objetivo, não é necessário fazer o `for`.